# Use multiple Google Cloud Service accounts for single compute engine instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have two google service account to access data in two different projects. Compute engine instance is running in the third account. One service account, I want to use to fetch data from first project bucket and the second one to upload data to again the second project while orchestrating workflow from the third project. Is it even possible to assign two service accounts to one compute engine instance?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a way to assign one instance two service account and i merged two service account into one with more limited permissions.